# US tourist visa after being denied but with transit visa

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, nicaraguan-citizens

My sister-in-law from Nicaragua was denied a tourist visa to visit us in the U.S. about 2 years ago.  Since then, he has gotten a transit visa for the U.S. and has traveled through the U.S. to the Netherlands to visit her boyfriend.

She will be going to the Netherlands again soon and we would love it if she could visit us but I'm not sure if she has a chance at a visa now.  Before she was working and now she isn't, but it seems to me she has demonstrated that she would not be coming her to stay illegally, because she has traveled here in transit (just to make connecting flights).  Is it worth applying for a visa?  Could she apply while she is in Holland and if so, how would that effect her odds of getting the visa?

Comment: Some clarification would help people answer.  One point you call her your sister in law and another point she is going to visit her boyfriend.  Has she married since the first try?  Does she have residency in Netherlands or just a visa to visit?

Comment: She is my wife's sister. Never married but engaged to her boyfriend in Holland. They are working on her immigration visa for the Netherlands but currently she can just visit their for 90 days. She got and has used a US transit visa after being rejected for a tourist visa - but since she is flying through the US to the Netherlands (this will be her 3rd time), I figure it would be nice to have her stay a few days and visit us. But that is not allowed on a transit visa.

Comment: The fact that she has visited the Netherlands on several occasions without issue will likely be a positive factor when they consider her request.  But not a guarantee of success.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be *less* likely she would be granted a visa if she applied for it in the Netherlands instead of her home country.

Unlike many countries, the US will allow people to apply for a nonimmigrant visa from any country they're legally present in, even as a tourist (unless they've had a previous visa cancelled at the border, then they must do it from their home country). So, she *can* apply for it there.

The problem is twofold: First, that the US embassy there will find it much more difficult to verify any relevant documents from Nicaragua, and if they are unable to verify information, the visa could be refused. Second, that she might not have the documents with her to begin with!

Then again, if she is relying on her boyfriend to support her, it may be better to apply for the visa in the Netherlands, as *his* information would be more relevant, and easier to verify from the Netherlands. But this would be a stronger case if they were already married.